# improve performance of insertions using MySQL for 10 million records in 5 tables

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

```
*env: windows 10 version mysql 5.7 Ram 32GB ide : toad mysql*
```

Count of records is 11308147.

I have 5 like tables

I have sufficient hardware requirement but issue is the performance of insert into simple table that does not have any relation ships. I need to have index on the table.

table structure

```
 CREATE TABLE `2017` (
      `MOB_NO` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL,
      `CAF_SLNO` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
      `CNAME` varchar(58) DEFAULT NULL,
      `ACT_DATE` varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
      KEY `2017_index` (`MOB_NO`,`ACT_DATE`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

I am using below for inserting the records into table. with out index it took around 45 min with out indexing and with out set statements where as with indexing it took 22 hrs still going on.

```
   SET autocommit=0;
    SET unique_checks=0;
    SET foreign_key_checks=0;
    LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'D:/base/test/2017/2017.txt' 
    INTO TABLE `2017` COLUMNS TERMINATED BY '|';
    commit;
```

I have seen suggestion to change cnf file, Could not find any in my machine. I would request some one to help me in this concern. I have been working on this for past 7 days but there is no improvement in the performance.

Comment: You insert data into working table? Maybe insert into empty temporary and then insert to working with autocommit/checks disabled will be faster? And removing indices before with recreating after is safe too.

Comment: No i am not inserting inyo working table. I have tried with out index (dumping data into table) and creating index on top of it ,it did not work for me.

Comment: Are other processes querying the table while you run the insert?  You mentioned you've tried creating the table, loading the data, then adding the index, but "it did not work for me"... why didn't that work?

Comment: no other process is running, "it did not work for me" what i mean by this is i have created index on top of the data where data was dump but it took more than a day still it was running using alter script

Comment: achieved to 2hr inserting 10 million records in approx 2 hrs by adding below lines in ini file
innodb_autoinc_lock_mode =2
sync_binlog=1
bulk_insert_buffer_size=512M
key_buffer_size=512M
read_buffer = 50M

Answer (score 0):

- A date in a `VARCHAR`?  That will probably be a nuisance later.
- No `PRIMARY KEY`?  Naughty.  If it is a "mapping" table, see [*my tips and justficications*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/index_cookbook_mysql#many_to_many_mapping_table)
- What order are the rows in?  If the incoming data is roughly in the same order as some index, then that index will be more efficiently built.  (This won't explain 22 hours.)
- What is the value of `innodb_buffer_pool_size`, and how much RAM is there?  For 4GB of RAM, I recommend `innodb_buffer_pool_size 2G`
- `key_buffer_size` applies to MyISAM, not InnoDB.  Use 20M if not using MyISAM.

Adding the secondary key *after* the `LOAD` will probably make it run faster.  However, it won't explain 22 hours.  In InnoDB, any `KEY` other than `PRIMARY KEY` is a 'secondary key'.  Currently `(mob_no, act_date)` is a secondary key.  (but it may be come `PRIMARY` if this is a mapping table).

Comment: thanks James for reply.
1) I have changed to date , I have issue as mentioned.
2) primary reason why I have not used PRIMARY Key, the tables are Mapping data.
3) Order ? is that ASC or DESC that you are taking about then it does not have any order.
4)I am using 4GB ram, intel i5
5)I have just followed trail and error method(it is mentioned in some link), thanks for the info. I will remove it.
6) its two different words , typo error.
on your suggestion about secondary key, what is this one ? any links to know more about it(I am very new to Database)

Comment: @raghavendraprasadgudipalli - I integrated my responses into my Answer.